# Chart.js 2.0 reduce gap between chart and y-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When the label is long, the y-axis is pushed to the left. It left a gap between the y-axis and the bar chart. Is there anyway to close the gap?

[image]

```
var labelList = ["Professional & Disciplinary Knowledge","Curriculum Planning and Instructional Delivery","Learning Environment","Creative Thinking","Problem solving and Critical Thinking","Research Skills"];


    var barDatasource = {
    labels: labelList,
    datasets: [
    ]
};
    var barConfig =  {
        type: 'bar',
        data: barDatasource,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        suggestedMax: 4
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: []
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Radar Chart for WM Component Mean',
                fontSize: 14,
                fontStyle: 'bold'
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Where's your code?  What have you tried so far?  please see [Ask] for why this question is not properly asked.

Comment: Sorry. Edited. Not sure enough information or not. I search a lot of post already. Not sure where to start to narrow the gap.